# How to change the text element in Eclipse?

Tags: html, eclipse

Simple question. I heard there was a text element that you can change from Auto, HTML, and/or Text.

I was told it would be at the top of the window, but I cannot find it anywhere.

I'm trying to give a row a commend to get the value of another row and add it to the end of a URL, but I can't seem to find the HTML element.

`https://www.domain.com/....<VALUE-OF>row["whatever"]</VALUE-OF>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I feel stupid about this. But I found the answer.

I was looking in the wrong place, it's in the text window, not the actual eclipse window.

[image]